# HP Proliant DL380 G5 won't power on

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant

I am trying to repurpose one of our DL 380 G5 servers. Originally we had two of these, put into production the same day and purchased from the same PO, that had their VGA ports go bad on their system boards. I ordered two new system boards and have been having headaches sense.

When I replaced the system board with a new one the server wouldn't turn on at all. The green LEDs on the back of the two power supplies do not light up and the power button on the front doesn't light up as well. There is an array of six small LEDs on the actual system board that are blinking and the PCI riser has a LED that is labled "AC Check" that also just blinks. Since I ordered two I figured I may of got a bad one and swapped it out with another board with the same results.

Next I thought perhaps the power supplies went but was lucky enough to have two spares. I swapped those out with no results. I verified that all 4 power supplies work in another DL 380 G5 that does work. I decided to order another power supply backplane thinking that could be the issue but still no results.

I cleared CMOS and changed the battery to be safe and still didn't power on. We have eight sticks of RAM and I tested each one individually and still no powering on.

Unfortunately this particular server is out of warranty but I still gave HP a call to see if they could shine some light on my troubles. They mentioned that the CPU could of went so try replacing that. Thankfully I had another CPU since we wanted to go from one to two so I swapped that out but it still doesn't power on and gives the same blinking LEDs mentioned above.

Does anyone have thoughts? Perhaps I am missing something or maybe I should just scrap the darn thing and move on...

Comment: You ordered all these parts for machines  five years old and out of warranty?

Comment: Only about $60 in parts. The rest we had on site for other servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a lot of work for ancient 2006-2008-era servers. I wouldn't bother trying to repair/replace a motherboard, when you can just [get another unit for $60](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Servers-/11211/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=dl380%20g5&rt=nc&LH_BIN=1).

But a bigger lesson is that servers of this vintage may not even be fit for repurposed use. Is the headache worth it?

For repair, though, please reference the [HP DL380 G5 Maintenance and Service Guide](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c00710359.pdf)... Just to make sure you've covered the repairs properly.

Comment: I am in full agreement. I can't purchase through eBay (government organization) and the application ran on this system can't be virtualized according to the vendor. I was told to try and repair it and here I am. Appreciate the link and will go over it but I am thinking its time to just salvage it and try to justify purchasing something newer. Thanks for the reply!